# Force long word to break inside div, but keep spaces between words

Tags: css, html

I am having trouble forcing a text to stay inside a div in a correct manner. The div doesn't have a width set.

I have **word-break:break-all** to prevent very long words (larger than the div width) from overflowing outside the div. It does the job.

But the problem is smaller words aren't being broken to the next line completely with this property set. They are being cut within the word, not at a space.

I tried **overflow-wrap:break-word**; and also **word-wrap:break-word** as i understood by reading other articles, but doesn't work.

**EDIT**: A JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xt9rj9d4/ if you remove

```
word-break:break-all;
```

You will see the behaviour i'm saying.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please.

Comment: may be stupid, but have you tried to use `text-align: justify;` to at least get the nearest solution?

Comment: Is it static words? or will it change later?

Comment: Here's a http://jsfiddle.net/xt9rj9d4/ to give better example

Comment: I know you said that you tried this howver, I do not see what is wrong with it http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/xt9rj9d4/4/

Comment: Because the very long word ("nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn") goes outside the div. I mention this specifically in my post topic.

Comment: Can you tell me at what point the nnnnn goes out of the div? Because I do not see it, what browser are you using?

Comment: I see small words together and the long one breaking http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/xt9rj9d4/2/ specifically what are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you specify how this does not solve your issue it will stay as my best answer: It sets all perameters you ask in your question  http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/xt9rj9d4/9/

```
div {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: No, as the "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn" goes outside the screen instead of breaking to next line at the end of the div.

Comment: Umm, no it does not. Try refreshing your browser with F5 or tell us what browser you are using because it is NOT leaving the div.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith `break-word` is non-standard value for `word-break` CSS property — http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov the fiddle is correct but I mis-typed it in the answer, you are correct on that part, however I still do not see what the OP is talking about, do you?

Comment: I'm seeing it go outside the screen in FF, but not in Chrome.  Maybe that's the difference.  @Dillinger, what browser are you using?

Comment: @xdhmoore What version of FF? I have 39.0 and it is working for me.

Comment: Mah, my bad.  I think I was looking at an old version of the jsfiddle.  Not seeing it anymore.

Comment: I *do* see it in the /4 version, from your first post, fwiw. In FF but not Chrome.  But not in the /9 version in this answer.

Comment: LOL, I am confused. I have 5 different fiddles up at any given time, between SO and work, I get lost in what I am doing. Good chance I have this fiddle saved with different sub folder somewhere else in lala land.